# Поставить троеточие в не вместившейся в поле текст

Tags: php, html, css, текст

На многих сайтах видно, что невместившейся текст обрезается, ставится троеточие и ссылка "подробнее".

В CSS нашел свойство `text-overflow`, но оно обрезает сразу на первой строке.
Как добиться того, чтобы текст обрезался на 3 или 4 строке допустим?

Comment: css - это совсем другая история

Comment: почему же ? есть же text-overflow.

Comment: по тому что это свойство пока официально не входит в CSS3 и носит черновой характер.

Comment: Если нужна многострочность, то тут можно легко и без text-overflow обойтись. И без php. Можно сделать троеточие ссылкой, кликнув по которой открывался бы весь текст.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

с помощью PHP можно делать вот так к примеру:

```
$text = "Допустим здесь ваш текст из 1000 символов";
$text = mb_substr($text,0,140, 'UTF-8'); //140 это кол. знаков
echo $text.'...';
```

Это самый простой пример

```
{
    $text1 = "Допустим здесь ваш текст из 1000 символов"; 
    $text = mb_substr($text1,0,140, 'UTF-8'); //140 это кол. знаков 
    $str_count = substr_count($text," "); // возвращает количество пробелов 
    $text = explode(" ", $text1); //количество слов 
    for($i=0;$i<$str_count; $i++){ echo $text[$i].' '; } echo "...";
}
```

Comment: Это да. Но я бы лучше не отрезал от последнего слова символы ,а завершал его. Красивее как-то будет смотреться.

Comment: да, я согласен.

Comment: Думал над таким алгоритмом, но дело в том, что есть длинные слова, есть короткие, а переносятся строки по словам, поэтому неизвестно, где будет обрыв, на 2, 3 или 4 строчке.

Comment: {$text1 = "Допустим здесь ваш текст из 1000 символов";
$text = mb_substr($text1,0,140, 'UTF-8'); //140 это кол. знаков
$str_count = substr_count($text," "); // возвращает количество пробелов
$text = explode(" ", $text1); //количество слов
for($i=0;$i<$str_count; $i++){
 echo $text[$i].' ';
 }
echo "...";}

Вот это не будет слов обрезать и количество символов не будет превышать указанное количество

Answer (score 6):

В PHP сколько функций для работы со строками, что вариантов можно скомбинировать множество. 
Например, мой такой:

```
$raw = 'Строка на много символов...'; 
$string = substr($raw, 0, 140); // обрезаем первые 140 символов
$end = strlen(strrchr($string, ' ')); // длина обрезка 
$string = substr($string, 0, -$end) . '...'; // убираем обрезок добавляем троеточие
echo $string;
```

Comment: Я не ТС но я принял этот ответ)

Answer (score 5):

Используйте этот код для PHP:

```
mb_strimwidth("Hello World", 0, 10, "...");
```

Функция выведет `Hello W...`

Comment: Вы просто разрушили все велосипеды...

Answer (score 2):

Это можно легко сделать средствами css. Если правильно ими воспользоваться)

[Держите](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9sxQ/)

Comment: далеко не лучшее решение обрамлять в новый врап

Comment: +1, хотя пример хорош только потому что внутри текст удачно вписался в размеры. А вообще может оказаться так, что многоточие далеко оторвано от текста.

Answer (score 0):

Это делается скриптом php, где указывается количество видимых символов, а дальше троеточие

Answer (score 0):

text-overflow обрезает на первой строке т.к. у вас не указана высота блока в котором находится текст, попробуйте что-то вроде:

```
<style>
div.txtOver {
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
}
</style>
<div class="txtOver">
много много текста
</div>
```

Ну а правильнее и проще конечно сделать на php с помощью substr

Comment: без white-space: nowrap; Ваш пример сработает только если есть слово шире чем 300px

Comment: согласен, чуть поспешил, но в моем примере текст за пределы блока не вылезет, и если копнуть глубже то с помощью css к концу блока можно прилепить троеточие, но это уже пляски с бубном) всетки substr тут более в тему

Answer (score 0):

> Вы просто разрушили все велосипеды...

Функция mb_strimwidth режет "по живому". А функция выше на этой странице, режет по словам. Обернул в функцию, пример:

```
$text1 = "Ассоциация участников рынка лакокрасочных материалов в поддержку качества краски– «Подходы к формированию рынка качественных и безопасных лакокрасочных материалов строительного назначения»";

function textTrim($str, $len) {
$text = mb_substr($str,0, $len, 'UTF-8'); //140 это кол. знаков
$str_count = substr_count($text," "); // возвращает количество пробелов
$text = explode(" ", $str); //количество слов
$out = '';
for($i=0;$i<$str_count; $i++){ $out .= $text[$i].' '; } $out .= "...";
return $out;
}

echo textTrim($text1, 70)."\n"; //Выведет: Ассоциация участников рынка лакокрасочных материалов в поддержку ...
echo mb_strimwidth( $text1, 0, 70, "...");  //Выведет: Ассоциация участников рынка лакокрасочных материалов в поддержку ка...
```

Comment: Использование CSS не всегда может быть возможно. Например нужно сгенерировать PDF билет на мероприятие, где печатается название компании, Фамилия, Имя, ит.д. Пользователи могут ввести супер длинные названия как компании, так имени, и другие переменные. Чтобы не уродовать напечатанный билет съехавшими символами не вписавшимися в дизайн билета, нужно ограничивать подобными способами.