# Как правильно добавить в php файл код обрезки строки по количеству символов и многоточие в конце?

Tags: php

На stackoverflow в одном из ответов (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/190992/232533) нашел код для вставки в php с помощью которого можно обрезать строку по определенному количеству символов и добавить троеточие в конце. Вот найденный код :

```
{$text1 = "Допустим здесь ваш текст из 1000 символов";
 $text = mb_substr($text1,0,140, 'UTF-8'); //140 это кол. знаков 
 $str_count = substr_count($text," "); // возвращает количество пробелов
 $text = explode(" ", $text1); //количество слов 
 for($i=0;$i<$str_count; $i++){ echo $text[$i].' '; } echo "...";}
```

Со слов автора данного кода, этот код не будет обрезать слова (по среди слова), а количество символов не будет превышать указанное количество и будет добавлено троеточие после обрезного текста.

В моем php файле (весь код файла ниже) есть строка:  `'item_intro'=>mb_strimwidth(strip_tags($row->introtext,''.$allow_tags.''),0,$chars, "..."),` с помощью которой удалось обрезать строку по количеству символов (значение берется из настроек модуля и  указано в переменной `$chars`)и после обрезки добавить троеточие после текста.

Вроде все хорошо текст режиться троеточие добовляеться, но проблема в том, что слова могут обрезаться по середине слова, а хотелось бы чтобы в тексте до троеточия были только целые слова, что вроде как возможно сделать с помощью найденного кода (указан выше). У меня к сожалению не хватает знаний, сколько не бился, как прикрутить найденный код к моему php файлу. Помогите пожалуйста грамотно добавить найденный код в мой php-файл

Мой исходный php файл:

```html
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
if(!class_exists('YJme2Help') && !function_exists('YJme2Items'))// lets reuse them!
{ 


 class YJme2Help
 {
  
  static function YJme2Items($params)
  {
   /* prepare database */
   $db     = JFactory::getDBO();
   $user    = JFactory::getUser();
   $userId    = (int) $user->get('id');
   global $aid;
   $aid    = $user->get('aid', 0);
   $contentConfig   = JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_content' );
   $access2   = !$contentConfig->get('shownoauth');
   $nullDate   = $db->getNullDate();
   $date     = JFactory::getDate();
   if(intval(JVERSION) >= 3 ){ 
    $now =         $date->toSql() ; 
   }else{
    $now =         $date->toMySQL(); 
   }
   /* prepare default module params */
   $yj_mod_name  = basename(dirname(__FILE__));// 10-8-2011
   $item_source  = $params->get   ('item_source',1);// 10-8-2011
   switch ($item_source) {
    case 1 :   
     require('modules/'.$yj_mod_name.'/yjme/get_joomla.php');
     require_once('modules/'.$yj_mod_name.'/yjme/jomfunctions.php');
     break; 
    case 2:  
     require('modules/'.$yj_mod_name.'/yjme/get_k2.php');
     require_once('modules/'.$yj_mod_name.'/yjme/k2functions.php');
     break;
   }

   //  this is the main array for k2/joomla news items. both use same vars for ouptut
   $main_yj_arr = array();
   foreach ( $load_items as $row ) {

    switch ($item_source) {
     case 1 :
      $item_url   = yjme_get_url($row);
      $img_url    = yjme_art_image($row);
      $cat_url   = yjme_get_cat_url($row);
      $author_url  = yjme_get_author_url($row);
      $advert_url  = yjme_advert($row);
      $advert_img  = yjme_advert_img($row);
      $item_media  = yjme_media($row);
      $item_hook  = yjme_hookon($row);
      $item_playlist = yjme_playlist($row);
      if(JPluginHelper::getPlugin('system', 'jcomments')){
        $config = JCommentsFactory::getConfig();
        $categories = $config->get('enable_categories');
        $ids = explode(',', $categories);
        if(in_array($row->catid,$ids)){
         //print_r($ids);
         $comments_on = 1;
         $comments_count =  $row->ccount;
        }else{
         $comments_on = 0;
         $comments_count =  0;
        }
      }else{
       $comments_on  = 0;
       $comments_count = 0;
      }
     break;
      case 2:
      $img_url   = k2_yjme_art_image($row);
      $item_url  = k2_yjme_get_url($row);
      $cat_url   = k2_yjme_get_cat_url($row);
      $author_url  = k2_yjme_get_author_url($row);
      $advert_url  = k2_yjme_advert($row);
      $advert_img  = k2_yjme_advert_img($row);
      $item_media  = k2_yjme_media($row);
      $item_hook  = k2_yjme_hookon($row);
      $item_playlist = k2_yjme_playlist($row);
      $comments   = json_decode($row->categoryparams);
      if(isset($comments->itemComments)){
       $comments_on  =  $comments->itemComments;
       $comments_count =  $row->ccount;
      }else{
       $comments_on = 0;
       $comments_count =  0;
      }
     break;
    }

    $yj_get_items = array(
      'item_title'   => htmlspecialchars($row->title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
      'item_url'    => $item_url,
      'item_intro'   => mb_strimwidth(strip_tags($row->introtext,''.$allow_tags.''),0,$chars, "..."),
      'img_url'    => $img_url,
      'cat_title'   => htmlspecialchars($row->cattitle, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ,
      'cat_url'    => $cat_url,
      'item_author'   => $row->username,
      'item_author_rn'  => $row->realname,
      'author_url'   => $author_url,
      'item_date' => JHTML::_('date', $row->created,JText::_('YJ_DATE_FORMAT')),
      'item_id'    => $row->id,
      'advert_url'   => $advert_url,
      'advert_img'   => $advert_img,
      'item_hits'    => $row->hits,
      'item_likes'   => $row->likes,
      'item_comments'  => $comments_on,
      'comments_count'  => $comments_count,
      'item_media'    => $item_media,
      'item_hook'    => $item_hook,
      'item_playlist'   => $item_playlist,
     );
     $main_yj_arr[] = $yj_get_items;
   }
   
     return $main_yj_arr;

  }
  
  
 }
}

?>
```

Если приведенный выше найденный код не совсем подходит для решения моей задачи, буду признателен за решение, как это можно реализовать по другому.

Comment: Вопрос немного сложнее, чем кажется. В строке могут быть знаки препинания (даже троеточие), а приведенный код учитывает только пробелы.

Answer (score 4):

А у меня получилось так:

```
<?php

$text = 'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!';

$l = mb_strlen($text);

function reduction($text, $length) {
    $lt = mb_strlen($text);
    if ($lt <= $length) return $text;
    $repl = preg_replace('/^(.{0,'.$length.'})\b\W.*$/u', '\\1', $text);
    $lr = mb_strlen($repl);
    if ($lr > $length) {
        $repl = mb_substr($repl, 0, $length) . '...';
    } else if ($lr < $lt) {
        $repl .= '...';
    }
    return $repl;
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h3>Длина исходной строки: <?php echo $l ?>.</h3>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>До скольки символов обрезать</th>
  <th>Результат</th>
 </tr>
 <?php
    for ($i = mb_strlen($text)+5; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>".reduction($text, $i)."</td></tr>";
    }
 ?> 
</table>
</body></html>
```

Результат:

```
Длина исходной строки: 41.

До скольки символов обрезать    Результат
46  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!'
45  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!'
44  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!'
43  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!'
42  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!'
41  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!'
40  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к...'
39  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к...'
38  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к...'
37  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и...'
36  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и...'
35  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится...'
34  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится...'
33  'Laravel стремится!!! Это...'
32  'Laravel стремится!!! Это...'
31  'Laravel стремится!!! Это...'
30  'Laravel стремится!!! Это...'
29  'Laravel стремится!!! Это...'
28  'Laravel стремится!!! Это...'
27  'Laravel стремится!!! Это...'
26  'Laravel стремится!!! Это...'
25  'Laravel стремится!!! Это...'
24  'Laravel стремится!!! Это...'
23  'Laravel стремится...'
22  'Laravel стремится...'
21  'Laravel стремится...'
20  'Laravel стремится...'
19  'Laravel стремится...'
18  'Laravel стремится...'
17  'Laravel стремится...'
16  'Laravel...'
15  'Laravel...'
14  'Laravel...'
13  'Laravel...'
12  'Laravel...'
11  'Laravel...'
10  'Laravel...'
9   'Laravel...'
8   'Laravel...'
7   'Laravel...'
6   'Larave...'
5   'Larav...'
4   'Lara...'
3   'Lar...'
2   'La...'
1   'L...'
0   '...'
```

А если заменить мою функцию `reduction()` на вариант из [ответа @Эдуард](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/731259/239133), то получается так:

```
Длина исходной строки: 41.

До скольки символов обрезать    Результат
46  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!'
45  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!'
44  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!'
43  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!'
42  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!'
41  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и к!!!'
40  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и ... '
39  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и ... '
38  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и ... '
37  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится и ... '
36  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится ... '
35  'Laravel стремится!!! Это относится ... '
34  'Laravel стремится!!! Это ... '
33  'Laravel стремится!!! Это ... '
32  'Laravel стремится!!! Это ... '
31  'Laravel стремится!!! Это ... '
30  'Laravel стремится!!! Это ... '
29  'Laravel стремится!!! Это ... '
28  'Laravel стремится!!! Это ... '
27  'Laravel стремится!!! Это ... '
26  'Laravel стремится!!! Это ... '
25  'Laravel стремится!!! Это ... '
24  'Laravel стремится!!! ... '
23  'Laravel стремится!!! ... '
22  'Laravel стремится!!! ... '
21  'Laravel стремится!!! ... '
20  'Laravel ... '
19  'Laravel ... '
18  'Laravel ... '
17  'Laravel ... '
16  'Laravel ... '
15  'Laravel ... '
14  'Laravel ... '
13  'Laravel ... '
12  'Laravel ... '
11  'Laravel ... '
10  'Laravel ... '
9   'Laravel ... '
8   'Laravel ... '
7   'Laravel ... '
6   'Laravel ... '
5   'Laravel ... '
4   'Laravel ... '
3   'Laravel ... '
2   'Laravel ... '
1   'Laravel ... '
0   'Laravel ... '
```

Как это прикрутить к вашему коду:

```
$text1 = "Допустим здесь ваш текст из 1000 символов";

/* здесь вставляете функцию `reduction()` - Эдуарда или мою... */

echo reduction($text1, 140);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я согласно вашим выкладкам стремился получить второй вариант (как у @Эдуарда) т.е. оставлять только целые слова.. Не подскажите как этот код прикрепить к моему php файлу (файл есть в вопросе)?? У меня не хватает знаний.. бьюсь пол дня, все предложенные варианты/решения рабочие, а как их прикрутить к моему файлу - не могу, не получается(( Если что в моем файле код строки которую нужно резать начинается со слов `'item_intro'`

Comment: @Alexander Zonov есть различия между нашими ф-ями :) Они в том, что моя не "режет" слишком короткие слова. Например, если вызвать вашу ф-цию `echo reduction($text, 3);` то вы увидите `Lar...` Мой вариант возвращает слово целиком: `Laravel ... ` И ещё, если не ошибаюсь, ваш вариант не корректно отрабатывает на кириллице.

Comment: @Эдуард, Вашу функцию я тоже уважаю, потому привел в ответе и результаты теста с ней.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov с кириллицей всё ок ) [ваш вариант:](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f5d5112c58520cc724676364a30e36d32cfef66)

Comment: @Эдуард, из вашего ответа понял, что вы это делали для продакшена. Тогда лучше всего делать на C как расширение к PHP. Там все получается и просто, и логично - перебор символов utf-8 в цикле. И скорее всего, такое уже должно быть сделано. Может даже в стандартной либе.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov я только на php пишу ))

Answer (score 3):

Буквально сегодня писал такую же задачу для другого форума - посмотрите на результат этого кода:

```
$text = 'Laravel стремится преобразить процесс разработки PHP, это относится и к локальной среде разработки. Vagrant обеспечивает простой, элегантный способ настройки управления виртуальными машинами.';

echo reduction($text);


function reduction($text, $length = 70) {
    if (mb_strlen($text, 'UTF-8') > $length) {
        $substr = mb_substr($text, 0, $length, 'UTF-8');

        $text = strpos($substr, ' ') !== false 
            ? preg_replace('~(\s)?(?(1)\S+$|\s$)~', '', $substr) 
            : strstr($text, ' ', true);

        $text .= ' ... ';
    }

    return $text;
}
```

**UPD:** [Посмотреть результат](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dde0061a8e0660007f9205e47b34f38fe999268d)

Comment: Уверен что ваш код работает как надо!) Проблема в том что я в php вообще плохо ориентируюсь, вот и возник вопрос как ваш или другой код решающий подобную задачу прикрутить к моему файлу.. В вопросе мой исходный файл привел полностью в надежде что кто-нибудь поможет добавить php-код  в файл

Comment: @Slava Я обновил свой ответ - добавил ссылку для просмотра результата его работы ( _перейти по ссылке и нажать на кнопку под кодом_ **execute code** ) ... Ну а в вашем коде, кроме вас, врятли кто-то будет разбираться.